# CSS can't operate

Tags: html, css

I have one problem: I have simple HTML code and CSS code, but the CSS doesn't work... Please, can you told me, when I have something wrong?:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://eslgfx.net/nodelogo/lol_small.ico"/>
    <title> LOL (fake :D) </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body link="#CDA221" vlink="lime" alink="#CDA221">
  <body background=http://i.imgur.com/0TugbQI.png">
  <h1> My page </h1>    


  <form name="form" method="post" action="file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Filip/Desktop/formular.html">
  <br> Please, enter your personal data:<br>
  Name: <input type="text" name="meno" maxlength="20"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Odoslať">
  <style type="css">
  input[type="submit"] {
    background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px; 
    border: 0;
}
  <style>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The out put is: [image]
I want to change "submit" button appearance. Please help.

Comment: Try `type="text/css"`. Might be a browser MIME issue.

Comment: You have to correct your html. 2 body tags for example.
Then close style tag with </style>

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

instead of:

```
<style type="css">
```

Also, you just need one `<body>` tag and you're missing open `"` for `background` value:

```
<body background="http://i.imgur.com/0TugbQI.png"link="#CDA221" vlink="lime" alink="#CDA221">
<!-- ------------^ Missing " here -->
```

as well as closing your `<style>` tag using `</style>`

Comment: wow...i always wanted to have so eagle sharp eyes...+1 for last edit!! :)

Answer (score 1):

`<style type="css">` is inconsistent across browsers!!

do it this way

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
   /* css styles*/
</style>
```

or simply :

```
<style>
   /* css styles*/
</style>
```

*you haven't closed your `<style>`* tag too!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two  tags to one

```
<body link="#CDA221" vlink="lime" alink="#CDA221" background=http://i.imgur.com/0TugbQI.png">
```

Use `"text/css"` instead of `"css"`

Put the `<style>` tag into the `<head>` tag.